# Why is my Badge Count Different

Tags: support, badges

Early July 19th I had 24 bronze badges

[image]

and now they are 23 what gives?

[image]

Comment: How did you know to take the first screenshot?

Comment: From an un-refreshed page.

Comment: Ahh, makes sense. I thought you were way too observant, way too paranoid, or maybe just clever. Number three it is.

Comment: I guess 1 and 3.  It just caught my eye, and I though it was weird.

Comment: What is the missing badge?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know.

Comment: I'd assume you got it on a post which was then deleted afterwards through moderation/flagging, but that's just me guessing, I'm in no way aware of the way the site is programmed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my guesswork. Considering that the system does not remove normal badges and only tag based badges can be withdrawn, I narrowed my focus on the number of votes you got on tags. I see you have 96 score on 12.04 right now.

From this, I conclude that you got a 12.04 badge earlier and that tag was removed from one of the question that you answered and hence you lost the badge for the time being. So, once you get more than 100 score in 12.04 tag, you will get back the tag. Hurray! :-)